# Accessing Session variables in views in Express

Tags: node.js, express

Im building a simple webpage with user registration and login

Trying to access variable `console.log(session.email);` results to `undefined`

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
     var session = req.session;
    console.log(session); 
    console.log(session.email); 

    // res.locals.user_id = req.session.id;

    next();
});
```

When I `console.log(session)` this are the results:

```
Session {
    cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-02-03T20:58:32.951Z,
     originalMaxAge: 6000000,
     httpOnly: false,
     secure: false },
  messages: [ 'Welcome Back' ],
  passport:
   { user:
      { id: 1,
        name: 'test',
        email: 'test@test.com',
        country: 'Europe',
        gender: 'Male',
        accountcreation: '2019-02-01T16:14:56.000Z',
        accountlastlogin: '',
        accountemailstatus: 0 } } }
```

Comment: Apparently the user's information are stored in passport object, like `session.passport.user.email`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works